# C#/.NET app using SimpleHttpServer not returning a response to browser?

Tags: c#, httplistener

NOTE: This is not a Python app, it is C#.

I have created a C# app I am trying to make into a simple server using this simple C# module I found on the web:

https://gist.github.com/aksakalli/9191056

I have everything wired up, but when I access my server from a browser, it never receives a response.  I checked this by using the *Network* tab in the Chrome debugger.  I see the request being made, but the Response sub-panel is always empty.

I traced my server code and it runs without error, but after adding the headers to the response and closing the output stream, nothing happens on the browser side.  Below are the relevants part of my code.  Can anyone tell me why my browser is never seeing a response and how I can fix this?

```
    public delegate Task<string> ProcessHttpContext(HttpListenerContext context);
    private ProcessHttpContext _processHttpContextFunc = null;

    public SimpleHTTPServer(string path, int port, ProcessHttpContext processHttpContextFunc)
    {
        this.Initialize(path, port);
        this._processHttpContextFunc = processHttpContextFunc;
    }

    public SimpleHTTPServer(string path)
    {
        //get an empty port
        TcpListener l = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 0);
        l.Start();
        int port = ((IPEndPoint)l.LocalEndpoint).Port;
        l.Stop();
        this.Initialize(path, port);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _serverThread.Abort();
        _listener.Stop();
    }

    private void Listen()
    {
        _listener = new HttpListener();
        _listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:" + _port.ToString() + "/main-page/");
        _listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = _listener.GetContext();
                Process(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception occurred during GetContext() call: " + ex.Message);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                    Debug.WriteLine("  Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    async private void Process(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("The context parameter is empty.");

        try
        {
                // Call it with the current context.
                string strResult = await this._processHttpContextFunc(context);
                byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strResult);

                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", strResult.Length.ToString());
                context.Response.SendChunked = false;
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
                context.Response.StatusDescription = "OK";
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                context.Response.OutputStream.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        }
        context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
    }

    private void Initialize(string path, int port)
    {
        this._rootDirectory = path;
        this._port = port;
        _serverThread = new Thread(this.Listen);
        _serverThread.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Can you see any error in browser console? Are you able to hit the breakpoint if you put in the start of the method??

Comment: I believe the status should be the first header, at leastt thats what the HTTP standard sais, may thats whats bothering the browser

Comment: Why not just use .netcore and create a proper dedicated webserver? it could be done in literally minutes, and works exactly how you would expect

Comment: Heres the link ro the response structure https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html

Comment: does it work on a port > 1000 and / or when you run it with admin privileges?

Comment: just tested the code from the gist with `_listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:" + _port.ToString() + "/");` and the "suitable port" constructor. Works fine with servering a text file.